# How to create custom vim commands for existing commands?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to put the following in .vimrc

```
:command Clip set mouse=v set nonumber set norelativenumber
```

To prepare for copying into (mouse)clipboard.

Error:
`Unknown option set`

Is there an alternative way to alias a list of vim commands?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:
You should specify `set` just once.

```
:command Clip set mouse=v nonumber norelativenumber
```